# Wildcard subnet mask for IPv6

Tags: postgresql, security

To allow any host to connect to PostgreSQL we can use the IPv4 wildcard subnet mask: `0.0.0.0/0`

I need this to setup my PostgreSQL's `pg_hba.conf` file correctly.

What is the IPv6 equivalent?

Comment: Isn't it just `::/0`? But surely this is off-topic here and better asked elsewhere?

Comment: How is it off-topic? I am trying to Administer my Database.

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan: I'm guessing that Colin probably thinks this is possibly off-topic because the IPv6 equivalent for 0.0.0.0/0 is going to be the same whether you're administering a database or writing a chat program, or something else.

Answer (score 1):

The IPv6 wilcard subnet mask is `::/0`

Comment: Neil - I edited this to use the more technical term since it will be easier for the average user to find.

Comment: @MaxVernon good call, thx